# phoneGap/Apache Cordova media capture plugin - multiple video recording

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to record multiple videos using phoneGap/Apache Cordova plugin but after every recording   it prompts to save or discard. How do I get rid of this option and autosave every video recording ? 
(I used duration options as 15 sec which it stops recording after 15 sec and then prompts to save or discard)

```
//  capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
var i, path, len;
for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    // do something interesting with the file
}
};

//  capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2, duration:15});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cordova plugin, it is not possible to change that behavior.

What the Cordova capture.captureVideo() JS method is doing is simply firing an intent with android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and then getting the file of saved video. The actual recording and save/discard (i.e., confirm/cancel) is handled by Android itself, not by the Cordova plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/src/android/Capture.java#L250

A quick look at the MediaStore API does not find any options to auto-save a capture.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Assuming that the video capture is user-triggered, my personal opinion is that it is good practice to let the user re-capture or discard the video if they don't like it, instead of automatically committing their capture.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable response.Is there any other scope to record video and save it automatically even when I use html5 to record video it does the same, prompts to save or discard.Can you please suggest me any way that I can multiple videos with time limit.

Comment: Can you suggest me any way possible to record videos in a mobile web application ????